# Turned off iCloud, but still deleted my photos from all devices

Tags: icloud, photos

I got a new phone (iphone 6s) so I wanted to wipe my old one (iphone 5s), once I had signed into icloud on my new device everything was recovered, photos, contacts, apps etc. So I turned off iCloud on my old phone so it wouldn't remove everything from my new phone and laptop. However when I deleted my photos it still deleted them off all my other devices, I have now lost over 1000 photos! It didn't wipe anything else I deleted just the photos! Is there a reason for this? Or anyway I can get my photos back?!

Comment: Try turning on iCloud again on the old phone, then saving them on a Mac, then you can turn iCloud off again.

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201351

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you misunderstand how iCloud Photo Library works. It syncs your photos so that all devices match at all times. Therefore, when you told it to delete your photos on your old phone, you were telling it to delete them everywhere. You can restore them from the Recently Deleted folder on your Photos app and/or www.iCloud.com.